# Size of complement of context-free language

Tags: fl.formal-languages, context-free

Let $L$ be a context-free language, $\bar L$ be its complement and $\bar L_n$ be the length $n$ words in $\bar L_n$.

> What is known about $|\bar L_n|$?

Note that [it is known](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/41878/number-of-words-of-length-n-in-a-context-free-language?rq=1) that $|L_n|$ is either polynomial (if $L$ is bounded$~$), or grows exponentially.
I wonder if anything similar might be true about $|\bar L_n|$.
Warning, $L$ is allowed to be ambiguous!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the proof that determining if a CFL ${L}$ = $\Sigma^*$ is undecidable, the set of strings $ID_0\#ID_1^R\#ID_2\#ID_3^R\#\ldots\#ID_t$ where $ID_0,ID_1,\ldots,ID_t$ is a list of the configurations of an accepting nondeterministic TM, is the complement of a context-free language. So $|\overline{L}_n|$ can basically be any computable function less than exponential.