# The number of words of length $n$ in a context-sensitive language

Tags: fl.formal-languages, space-bounded

Let $L$ be a context-sensitive language, $s_{L}(n)$ is denoted by the number of words of length $n$ in $L$.

What is known about $s_{L}(n)$?

Note that [it is known](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/41878/number-of-words-of-length-n-in-a-context-free-language?rq=1) that $s_{L}(n)$ is either polynomial, or grows exponentially if $L$ is a context-free language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/42190/size-of-complement-of-context-free-language.

Comment: A simple note: for every (total) function $f(n)$ that can be computed by a LBA with unary input, you can make $s_L(n) = f(n)$ (just check $x < f(n)$)